# mod-rewrite include actual files in a MediaWiki URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mediawiki

I just setup a local MediaWiki server and have been able to use `mod-rewrite` to do the following:

```
http://10.0.0.160/wiki/index.php?Main_Page
```

Into:

```
http://10.0.0.160/wiki/Main_Page
```

This works well now and I am happy with it however any file or folder is automatically redirected to the actual file, and not the wiki article. For example, MediaWiki installations contain a `LocalSettings.php` file at the root directory, and thus when I do the following:

```
http://10.0.0.160/wiki/LocalSettings.php
```

I am directed to the actual file and not:

```
http://10.0.0.160/wiki/index.php?LocalSettings.php
```

I hope there must be a way to do it, as when I go to Wikipedia and type in `en.wikipedia.org/LocalSettings.php`, I get a redirect response to the relevant page and therefore it doesn't go to their settings file.

The same issue happens with folders too.

The way I setup the redirecting was with a `.htaccess` in the main directory of the MediaWiki installation, and thus it contains the following directives as shown [**here**](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache) in a MediaWiki tutorial:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wiki/index.php [L]
```

Finally there is the path setup for my MediaWiki:

```
$wgScriptPath = "/wiki";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
```

Me not knowing much about Apache means I don't have a clue on where to go with this, so if more information is needed, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's these lines that are causing it:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
```

They mean that the following RewriteRule will only be executed if the request URL is *not* an existing file or directory. Or, as [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) have it: "Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a directory [or file]."

Which is what is required for those files that you want to actually serve up, like images, CSS, and Javascript.

Is your goal to be able to have a page on your wiki called `LocalSettings.php`?

To permit only the three PHP entry points and any images, and let anything else be a wiki page, you could add these rules before the others:

```
RewriteRule (index\.php|load\.php|api\.php)$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*\.(jpg|jpeg|pdf))$ - [L]
```

Comment: Hi Sam, still working on the site now. Yes that is my goal, and strangely I didn't think twice about writing those two down. I'll try now.

Comment: Ah, yes I tried this before. See the thing is now, when removing both, my pages load in plain-html with no CSS styling or images. I believe it is trying to reference a wiki-page on the back-end whereas it should be looking for the correct resources...

Comment: You're right, it's trying to treat everything then as a wiki page. I've updated my answer with how to prevent this for the various other files.

Comment: Beautiful! Worked perfectly. Thankyou very much for your swift response.

Comment: Oh great! :) And just remember to add any extra file extensions there that you want to support.

Comment: Hey Sam, just been uploading and now I'm also getting a `404 Not Found` when I try to open any uploaded images directly by clicking on them. `http://10.0.0.160/wiki/File:Flag.svg.png` is such a link. Any ideas? I added `png` and `svg` to the list but nothing happens.

Comment: You'll need `thumb.php` (and possibly `thumb_handler.php` depending on configuration) for files, `opensearch_desc.php` for browser search integration, `img_auth.php` if the wiki is private. [T180394](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T180394) is the task to clean up this mess.